# Part in classicthesis doesn't display capital roman numerals 

Tags: classicthesis, parts

Very soft question, perhaps: I'm writing a document using `classicthesis`. I divided it in parts with the`\part` command. So it has "Part I", "Part II", etc. But the link to this parts, as displayed in the PDF, says instead "Part i",...,"Part iii". How can I capitalize this numeration? [image]

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,%
                ngerman,american,%
                ]{scrreprt}

%\usepackage{classicthesis-preamble}
\input{classicthesis-config}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{american} 
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\part{Title zero}\label{part:z}
In \autoref{part:b} we will analyze ...
\part{Title one}\label{part:a}
As in \autoref{part:a}, this part \textit{blah blah}
\part{Title two}\label{part:b} 
\part{Title three}\label{part:c} 
\end{document}
```

I was asked to provide `classicthesis-config.tex`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{eulerchapternumbers,listings,drafting,%
                 pdfspacing,%floatperchapter,%linedheaders,%
                 subfig,beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}                                        

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{enable-backrefs} % enable backrefs in the bibliography
\setboolean{enable-backrefs}{false} % true false

\newcommand{\myTitle}{A Classic Thesis Style\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySubtitle}{An Homage to The Elements of Typographic Style\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDegree}{Doktor-Ingenieur (Dr.-Ing.)\xspace}
\newcommand{\myName}{Andr\'e Miede\xspace}
\newcommand{\myProf}{Put name here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myOtherProf}{Put name here\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySupervisor}{Put name here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myFaculty}{Put data here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDepartment}{Put data here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myUni}{Put data here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myLocation}{Darmstadt\xspace}
\newcommand{\myTime}{August 2012\xspace}
\newcommand{\myVersion}{version 4.1\xspace}

\newcounter{dummy} % necessary for correct hyperlinks (to index, bib, etc.)
\newlength{\abcd} % for ab..z string length calculation
\providecommand{\mLyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
\newcommand{\ie}{i.\,e.}
\newcommand{\Ie}{I.\,e.}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.\,g.}
\newcommand{\Eg}{E.\,g.} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{latin9}{inputenc} % latin9 (ISO-8859-9) = latin1+"Euro sign"
 \usepackage{inputenc}              

\usepackage{babel}                  

\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers}{natbib}
 \usepackage{natbib}                

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}       
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
    \usepackage{fontenc}     
\usepackage{textcomp} % fix warning with missing font shapes
\usepackage{scrhack} % fix warnings when using KOMA with listings package          
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right  
\usepackage{mparhack} % get marginpar right
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % fixes some LaTeX stuff 
\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused,smaller}{acronym}
    \usepackage{acronym} % nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis

\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1}\hfill} % fix the list of acronyms


\usepackage{tabularx} % better tables
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % increase table row height
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % to be used with each float for alignment
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang,font=small}
\usepackage{subfig}  

\usepackage{listings} 
%\lstset{emph={trueIndex,root},emphstyle=\color{BlueViolet}}%\underbar} % for special keywords
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,%C++,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},%\bfseries,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    %identifierstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
    commentstyle=\color{Green}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    numbers=none,%left,%
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,%\tiny
    stepnumber=5,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=single,
    belowcaptionskip=.75\baselineskip
    %frame=L
} 

\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
    \usepackage{hyperref}  % backref linktocpage pagebackref
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1 
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex}{graphicx}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
\newcommand{\backrefnotcitedstring}{\relax}%(Not cited.)
\newcommand{\backrefcitedsinglestring}[1]{(Cited on page~#1.)}
\newcommand{\backrefcitedmultistring}[1]{(Cited on pages~#1.)}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{enable-backrefs}}%
{%
        \PassOptionsToPackage{hyperpageref}{backref}
        \usepackage{backref} % to be loaded after hyperref package 
           \renewcommand{\backreftwosep}{ and~} % separate 2 pages
           \renewcommand{\backreflastsep}{, and~} % separate last of longer list
           \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}  % disable standard
           \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{% detailed backref
              \ifcase #1 %
                 \backrefnotcitedstring%
              \or%
                 \backrefcitedsinglestring{#2}%
              \else%
                 \backrefcitedmultistring{#2}%
              \fi}%
}{\relax}    
\hypersetup{%
    %draft, % = no hyperlinking at all (useful in b/w printouts)
    colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,%
    % uncomment the following line if you want to have black links (e.g., for printing)
    %colorlinks=false, linktocpage=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,% 
    breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
    plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
    hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,%nesting=true,%frenchlinks,%
    urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webgreen, %pagecolor=RoyalBlue,%
    %urlcolor=Black, linkcolor=Black, citecolor=Black, %pagecolor=Black,%
    pdftitle={\myTitle},%
    pdfauthor={\textcopyright\ \myName, \myUni, \myFaculty},%
    pdfsubject={},%
    pdfkeywords={},%
    pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},%
    pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref and classicthesis}%
}   

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}%
    {%
       \addto\extrasamerican{%
                    \renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Figure}%
                    \renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{Table}%
                    \renewcommand*{\partautorefname}{Part}%
                    \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
                    \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}%     
                }%
       \addto\extrasngerman{% 
                    \renewcommand*{\paragraphautorefname}{Absatz}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subparagraphautorefname}{Unterabsatz}%
                    \renewcommand*{\footnoteautorefname}{Fu\"snote}%
                    \renewcommand*{\FancyVerbLineautorefname}{Zeile}%
                    \renewcommand*{\theoremautorefname}{Theorem}%
                    \renewcommand*{\appendixautorefname}{Anhang}%
                    \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}{Gleichung}%        
                    \renewcommand*{\itemautorefname}{Punkt}%
                }%  
            % Fix to getting autorefs for subfigures right (thanks to Belinda Vogt for changing the definition)
            \providecommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}%             
    }{\relax}
\makeatother

\usepackage{classicthesis}
```

Comment: What is `classicthesis-preamble`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the `parts` option for `classicthesis` (the file `classicthesis-config.tex` passes this option to `classicthesis`) issues

```
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\roman{part}}
```

To override this and to be able to use uppercased Roman numerals, add to the preamble

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}
```

Comment: @JorgeCampos You're welcome!

Comment: This solution has the undesired effect of changing the case in the TOC. Any other way of setting the upper roman after the TOC has been processed?

Comment: @juliohm feel free to open a fresh new follow-up question. There,  you can provide a little complete document showing the relevant settings and link to this question.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: It's really the same question, the issue is that upper case Roman takes effect on the table of contents of the classic-thesis.

Comment: I think it's okay, don't need to bother.

Comment: @juliohm This fixes the TOC issue:http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140053/11984. It's in fact a bug in classicthesis - even if you compile classicthesis.tex that comes with your distribution you notice that the roman numerals in the TOC are wrong.