# classicthesis part numerals TOC vs. in text

Tags: table-of-contents, capitalization, classicthesis, roman-numerals

My question is similar to this one [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73531/part-in-classicthesis-doesnt-display-capital-roman-numerals).

I use classicthesis and have the problem that

a) when I don't redefine `\thepart`, I get

- **lower case (instead of uppercase)** roman numerals in the TOC
- uppercase roman numeral in the text (on the "title page" of the part)

b) when I use `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}` in the preamble, I get

- upper case roman numerals **in small caps (instead of spaced low small caps)** in the TOC
- uppercase roman numeral in the text

c) when I use `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\Roman{part}}}}`in the preamble, I get

- upper case roman numerals in the TOC
- uppercase roman numeral in **low small caps (instead of standard font/capitalization)** in the text

What I want, is a combination of both:

- *upper case roman numerals in spaced low small caps* in the TOC
- *uppercase roman numerals in standard font/capitalization* in the text

EDIT:

sorry, here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,
               a4paper,
               footinclude=true,
               headinclude=true,
               titlepages
               %draft
               ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[linedheaders,
            eulermath,
            eulerchapternumbers,
            parts,
            floatperchapter]{classicthesis} 

% a) without a redefinition of \thepart
% --

% b) redefinition with uppercase roman number
% \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}

% c) redefinition with spaced low small caps
% \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\Roman{part}}}}

\begin{document}
% ******************************************************************************
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage\part{Introduction and Background}
\cleardoublepage\part{Empirical Studies}
\cleardoublepage\part{Conclusion}
\cleardoublepage\part{Appendix}
% ******************************************************************************
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt,
               a4paper,
               footinclude=true,
               headinclude=true,
               titlepage,
               %draft
               ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[linedheaders,
            eulermath,
            eulerchapternumbers,
            parts,
            floatperchapter]{classicthesis}

%%% Magic code; don't ask ;-)
\makeatletter
\def\ttl@tocpart{%
  \def\ttl@a{\protect\numberline{\thepart}\@gobble{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction and Background}
\part{Empirical Studies}
\part{Conclusion}
\part{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

#### Table of contents

[image]

#### Part page

[image]

Here is a more thorough revision; you have two choices: with the code as is there will be a simple space between the part number and the title; in the code you find how to align part titles to chapter titles instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt,
               a4paper,
               footinclude=true,
               headinclude=true,
               titlepage,
               %draft
               ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[linedheaders,
            eulermath,
            eulerchapternumbers,
            parts,
            floatperchapter]{classicthesis} 

% make the part links in the TOC point to the right page
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\oldpart}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}

\makeatletter
\def\ttl@tocpart{% %magic code, don't ask
  \def\ttl@a{\protect\numberline{\thepart}\@gobble{}}}

%% If you want part titles aligned with chapter titles
%% uncomment the following line and remove the code
%% up to (and excluding) \makeatother
% \setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{\cftchapnumwidth}

\let\classic@l@part\l@part
\renewcommand\l@part[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\textsc{##1} }%
  \classic@l@part{#1}{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction and Background}
\chapter{Pippo}
\part{Empirical Studies}
\part{Conclusion}
\part{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: regarding the roman number, yes, thank you, but you introduced a fixed width between the roman numeral and the name of the part that is larger than it is for the chapters/sections. I would like to have either the same fixed space between numeral and text as for the chapters/sections (preferred) or classicthesis' standard behavior, i.e., just a space after the numeral

Comment: @user21932 You can act on the space reserved for part numbers with `\setlength{\cftpartnumwidht}{...}` The initial value is approximately 2em in the text font. The magic code tells `titlesec` to write the TOC entry pertaining to parts in a way that's understandable by `tocloft`. If you want chapter and part titles aligned, issue `\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{\cftchapnumwidth}`

Comment: @user21932 I modified the code, you now may choose between two possibilities. I also added a trick for making the part titles into links to the right page.

Comment: Works great, thank you very much!! (linking to the right pages worked without your code, too, in my case...)

Comment: @egreg Is this an incompatibility between `titlesec` and `tocloft`? It appear that as soon as one specifies `\titleformat{\part}...`, the command `\cftpartpresnum` from tocloft loses all functionality (hence ignoring `\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{\scshape}` from classicthesis).

Comment: @Jörg I've never fully understood what goes wrong. I found that magic redefinition of `\ttl@tocpart` with trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I resolved it using egreg's answer, but I still had problems with cleveref references to parts (the numerals were still lowercase). I resolved this second problem adding this line in the header:

```
\crefformat{part}{Part #2\MakeUppercase{#1}#3}
```

or if you don't want the capitalized P:

```
\crefformat{part}{part #2\MakeUppercase{#1}#3}
```